# creating a book reading app but not able to list its contents in a particular way

Tags: android, ios, dataframe, user-interface, mobile

contents are not appearing on the screen as they intend to be, first page on which there should be the list of Books is working fine but on the event of clicking on any book the list of chapters got mixed up (every book has different chapters) and same is followed by in the sections page.

Hey Everyone, I'm newbie on OS(Outsystems), and I'm creating an app which provides reading articles to users.

On the starting page there should be the list of books (fortunately I already did this with pagination) then if any user click on any book from the list, next page would be of Chapters of that particular book (which divides the whole book, also every book contains different numbers of chapters) then on the event of clicking of any chapter user will see the sections of that particular chapter, lastly clicking on any section user will be able to see the real content of that section.

I was trying to make this on MS Excel so I can import but couldn't make it.

Is there any other way to do it, or if the excel is the only way how can I make/arrange/format it on excel in the same way or flow explained above?

Comment: Hi, is this Android? iOS? Can you add some of your code? Some or your errors?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.